# isdigit returning false for integer

Tags: python

I am opening a file 'testFile' and splitting it at commas. so far so good. The second value in one line is "30"
the line is "This is a, 30, test"
I can verify that it is splitting correctly because I can print parts[1] and it prints "30", but why is repeats.isdigit() returning false when this value is 30?

```
with open('testFile') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        parts = line.split( ',' )

        repeats = parts[1]
        print repeats.isdigit()
        print parts[1]
```

Comment: `" 30"` isn't `"30"`.

Comment: so is there an easy way to parse that/ignore the space and read it as the same?

Comment: Use  a try/except casting to int

Comment: @swinters user `.strip()` will ditch the whitespaces for you.

Comment: so many fancy python functions to learn. .strip made it work. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isdigit()` applied to " 30" will always return false, because of the white space before the "30". To fix this use the `.strip()` method before `isdigit()`

Answer (score 0):

```
You could use re.split. it can split on mult tokens.
import re
with open('data') as f:
    for line in f:
        # split on white space and commas
        line = re.split(r'[ ,]',line)
        # re.split leaves some empty strings, so remove them
        line = [el for el in line if el]
        print(line)
        print(line[3].isdigit())

['This', 'is', 'a', '30', 'test']

True
```